# Add a column in a tab delimited text file in python

Tags: python, multiple-columns

What's the easiest way to open a file, read a line, append to just that line and then close the file.

```
 with open(infile, 'w') as inf: 
      for line in inf:
          line = line.join(x)
```

But how to change/add to the the code so that I can add to the line in infile, or replace the line in infile without effecting the rest of the document?

I have been writing new files and deleting the old ones when done but this doesn't seem like very clever strategy. I would like to do this without using the csv module as I want to keep everything as simple text files.

Comment: There isn't an easy way to do that - *"lines"* don't really exist in the text file format.

Comment: seems like something `sed` could do very easily. Maybe you can call that from python?

Comment: A file is essentially a block of bytes, you can't just insert new content into the interior of that block without somehow moving the following bytes. BTW, `line = line.join(x)` is a strange thing to do.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is really helpful. I guess my question now is: Is there a good alternative to my current method?

Comment: The simple, robust way is to just do what you're doing. It *is* possible to insert new content into the original file if you _really_ want to do that, but you need to be able to store the old data from after the insertion point somewhere (either in RAM or in another file) so you can append it after the new content has been added. However, it's always safer to just write a new file and only delete the original once the new version is closed.

Comment: Thanks @PM 2Ring! I couldn't work out if I was missing something very obvious or if it was indeed a complicated issue. Your help is much appreciated!